# How do I handle connection errors in my database class when using `with` in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, psycopg2

In the following Database class if the connection fails my error is printed. But, a system error is also printed because the `__exit__` code fires.

> AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute '_conn'

How should I handle this type of situation?
`try/except` Or is there a better way?

```
import psycopg2
import mysecrets as ms
from time import time


class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, localhost=False):
        try:
            print(f"ATTEMPTING DATABASE CONNECTION")
            self._conn = psycopg2.connect(
                f"""
                dbname =    {ms.LOCALDB_NAME if localhost else ms.DB_NAME}
                port =      {ms.LOCALDB_PORT if localhost else ms.DB_PORT}
                user =      {ms.LOCALDB_USER if localhost else ms.DB_USER}
                password =  {ms.LOCALDB_PASS if localhost else ms.DB_PASS}
                host =      {ms.LOCALDB_HOST if localhost else ms.DB_HOST}
                """
            )
            self._cursor = self._conn.cursor()
            print(f"CONNECTED TO DATABASE\n")
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"UNABLE TO CONNECT TO DATABASE\n{error}")

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.connection.close()

    @property
    def connection(self):
        return self._conn

    @property
    def cursor(self):
        return self._cursor

    def commit(self):
        self.connection.commit()

    def query(self, sql, params=None):
        self.cursor.execute(sql, params or ())

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchone()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time()

    with Database() as db:
        elapsed_time = round(time() - start_time, 2)
        print(f"Testing database connection took {elapsed_time} seconds.")
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can initialize `self._conn` first thing, before the `try`, as `self._conn = None`, which makes it exist. Then, in the `__exit__`, `close`, etc. guard it with

```
if self._conn is not None:
    self._conn.close()
    self._conn = None
```

However, I don't think it's a good design the catch and ignore the general `Exception` error. It might be something other than a connection error. Even if it is, you end up with an uninitialized object. That's not useful, and will cause later errors. Better to catch them early and let it just pass from the `__init__`, and let whatever instantiated it deal with it.

Comment: Hi Keith.  Do you mean "let whatever instantiated it deal with it" in the way that Skam describes in his answer?

Comment: Yes. Either let the psycopg2 error pass, or raise one that might make more sense for your app. I would, however, use `... from error`, rather than `... from None`, so you don't lose the underlaying reason.

Answer (score 2):

First, catching `Exception` instead of a specific error is an antipattern. 
In Python, you should know what exceptions are thrown from your functions and handle them accordingly.

Second, if your call to `psycopg2.connect` or `_conn.cursor()` throws any error, then your code catches the exception and your instance variables `_conn` and `_cursor` are never set.
That is the cause of your `AttributeError`.

IMO, the right way to handle it would be to raise an error and do not continue with execution if your database class cannot connect to a database or let whatever code is using this class handle the error.

```
class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, localhost=False):
        try:
            print(f"ATTEMPTING DATABASE CONNECTION")
            self._conn = psycopg2.connect(
                f"""
                dbname =    {ms.LOCALDB_NAME if localhost else ms.DB_NAME}
                port =      {ms.LOCALDB_PORT if localhost else ms.DB_PORT}
                user =      {ms.LOCALDB_USER if localhost else ms.DB_USER}
                password =  {ms.LOCALDB_PASSWORD if localhost else ms.DB_PASSWORD}
                host =      {ms.LOCALDB_HOST if localhost else ms.DB_HOST}
                """
            )
            self._cursor = self._conn.cursor()
            print(f"CONNECTED TO DATABASE\n")
        except psycopg2.Error as error:
            raise ValueError(f"UNABLE TO CONNECT TO DATABASE\n{error}") from None
```

There's probably a better exception than `ValueError` to use.